# How to trick an application expecting a file:// to read from stdin?

Tags: pipe, stdin

A [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) makes it possible to specify an URI to a file stored locally, such as `file:///home/demo/sample`.

Could it be used to specify `stdin`?

For instance, with CURL:

```
curl file:///home/demo/sample
```

shows the contents of the file;

```
echo "Hello" | curl file:///dev/fd/0
```

gives **an empty result**, while I would expect it to show “Hello”. By the way:

```
echo "Hello" | cat /dev/fd/0
```

actually displays “Hello” to the output.

What should I put after `file://` to target `stdin`?

---

Context: I'm experimenting with [Motion](https://github.com/sackmotion/motion) which is able to read data from an HTTP URI or a file specified as `file://`, but doesn't seem to have an option to read a video stream directly from `stdin` (and [a related question](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/SupportQuestion2014x01x23x064801) asked nearly two years ago was never answered). I want to be able to trick the app to think that it reads a file, when it actually is reading the output from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: This is likely to be fairly application-dependent. I'd guess `curl` doesn't like reading a device file for its `file://` URLs, hence no easy `file:///dev/stdin` or similar. You might have better luck creating a FIFO and reading from that, or just using temp files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
curl file:///dev/fd/0
```

IS the correct way to make `curl` read from file descriptor 0 (`stdin`).

Take any readable textfile, do

```
<theTextFile.txt curl file:///dev/fd/0
```

And it should work just like `cat`.

Your problem is "How do I make curl read from a pipe?" and I'm afraid the answer is: *patch curl's source code*.

---

If you analyze the strace of curl on the example up top, you'll see it `mmap`s the file. `mmap`ing won't work if the file is a pipe. If curl used regular `read` and `write` system calls, there wouldn't be any difference between `<theTextFile.txt curl file:///dev/fd/0` and `cat theTextFile.txt curl | file:///dev/fd/0`, which is how it should be, IMO.